# RegularExpression with currency $ US or Canadian. Validating

Tags: php, regex

```
^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(\.\d{0,2})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2}?)$
```

I actually found this to help me to validate the amount of $. The problem is that I want to have a limited amount to validate between 0$ and 99.99$. also amounts like 01.20 and 10.1 are not acceptable but 1.20$  10.10 are.

Is there something I could modify on this regex.
Also this is for the use of my php code. I know I need to put one more backlash on the regex to make it work on php. thanks.

Comment: This actually matches possible prices with preceding `$`.

Comment: it matches almost everything with( 2 digits after the . ) Which I do not want

Comment: @EngjëllBislimi are you looking to match `0$` or `$0`?

Comment: between 0$ and 99,99$ so i guess 0$

Comment: @EngjëllBislimi are the commas `,` thousand separators or are they decimal point, or both formats?

Comment: @EngjëllBislimi also, what about `99.9$`?

Comment: someone gave me this one but it's really incomplete for what I need. so I<m sorry i cant answer to that

Comment: and it would be 99.90$

Comment: Does `^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})\$$` work for you?

Comment: yes! wow thank you . Could you explain to me what you did if possible. I appreciate it

Comment: @EngjëllBislimi moved to answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/6QFZjY/1)

```
^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})\$$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{2})?|\.\d{2})` Match either of the following options

  - `\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{2})?` Option 1

    - `\d{1,2}` Match a digit one or two times
    - `(?:\.\d{2})?` Optionally match a decimal point followed by exactly two digits
  - `\.\d{2}` Option 2. Match a decimal point followed by exactly two digits
- `\$` Match `$` literally
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2})(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?\$$
```

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2})` matches either a 0 or a non-zero digit once followed by an optional digit
- `(?:,?\d{3})*` matches an optional thousands separator followed by three digits zero or more times
- `(?:\.\d{2})?` optionally matches a decimal place followed by two digits
- `\$` literally matches the dollar sign symbol
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZMp6N/1)